# call a python script from ElasticSearch daily

Tags: python, django, elasticsearch, logstash, logstash-jdbc

I have `logstash` scheduled to read data from database every day at `3:00 A.M.`. What I want to do is whenever the index is read I want to call a `Python Function` defined in my `Django` Project that will process index and then update another index in `ElasticSearch`. 
Basically, I am fetching all transactions done daily via `logstash` and then want to run `python script`, if fetch was successful then process transactions (apply some machine learning stuff) and save result as another index in `Elasticsearch` so I want help with:

- **Call a python script from Elasticsearch when index is updated**

I was reading: [ElasticSearch docs for python script](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/plugins/5.3/lang-python-usage.html) but couldn't get as am new to ES and couldn't get how I will schedule it.
Though I can make the script running as separate thread in Django, and process ES data, I want to call it from ES, either daily or whenever the index is called.
If I can call multiple scripts that will be great add, as different scripts prcodess differently.
[Question on ES faq](https://discuss.elastic.co/t/custom-scripts-re-python-java/112500)

## UPDATED

also tried:

```
script_lang => "python"
script_type => "file"  # inline
script => "script.py"
```

in the output of `Logstash.conf` file, didn't seem to work.
My Script is saved in `config/scripts` folder
Script tag in output plugin of logstash [docs here.](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/logstash/current/plugins-outputs-elasticsearch.html#plugins-outputs-elasticsearch-script)

## UPDATED 2

Also did:

```
bin/logstash-plugin install logstash-output-exec
```

and then:

```
output {
stdout { codec => json_lines }
exec {
command => "echo hi"  # This works but for each document, hi, hi, hi...
-- If I replace with python path\script.py
}
}
```

As there is no way to execute exec only once as by [Elastic discussion](https://discuss.elastic.co/t/exec-only-once/28945)

Comment: if you are using Linux crontab is the tool to automatize it

Comment: @Wonka that will run python script at a specific time, what if there were so updates/pushes by logstash? or `logstash` it took too long to push, I have lots of different things going on, I was actually wondering if there was a way to call python script only after push from logstash rather than using cron, or language scheduler